# Show if $n \equiv 3$ (mod 7) then $x^3 +y^3 =n$ has no solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Show if $n \equiv 3$ (mod 7) then $x^3 +y^3 =n$ has no solution.

I know that $n \equiv 3$ (mod 7) implies $7 | n-3$ which implies $n = 7m+3,  
 m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So $x^3 + y^3 = 7m+3$  which means $ x^3 +y^3 -3 =7m$. I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What are the possible remainders of $x^3$ modulo $7$?

Comment: The possible remainders are 0,1, and 6.

Comment: So what remainders can you get as the sum of two cubes?

Comment: Would it be 0,1,2, and 6?

Comment: And one other. But that one's not $3$.

Comment: Would 5 be the other possibility?

Comment: Bull's eye @frostyfeet.

Answer (score 3):

The cubes in $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$ are $0$, $1$ and $-1$. Hence the sums of two cubes are $\;\bigl\{0,\, \pm 1,\,\pm2\bigr\}$. Neither $3$ nor $-3\,$ are in this list.